# How to fix react app with router to use basename of the local folder it's deployed in?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router

There's multiple folders on a server that has different versions of my react app like:

```
data/www/demo1
data/www/demo2
...
data/www/demo15
```

Each folder contain the files copied (without changing anything) from a dist folder of my app.

I can access each version of the the app by url like:

http://server/demo1

When I added routing to my app this didn't work anymore because I didn't have basename in router:

```
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
          <Route path="attributes" element={<Attributes />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<InfoPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

How can I define the base so that it gets the folder that app files are located in? Of course I could hadcode the basename, build and copy stuff to a folder with that name, but I'd have to repeat that 15 times if I had 15 folders. Can I do it so that the folder name would be used as the basename?

Answer (score 0):

The router takes a [`basename`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router#basename) prop for just this scenario.

> `basename`
>
> Configure your application to run underneath a specific basename in
> the URL:
>
> ```
> function App() {
>   return (
>     <BrowserRouter basename="/app">
>       <Routes>
>         <Route path="/" /> {/*  Renders at /app/ */}
>       </Routes>
>     </BrowserRouter>
>   );
> }
> ```

Add the appropriate `basename` URL path to each app's router.

Example:

```
data/www/demo1
```

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/demo1">
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<App />} />                 // "/demo1/"
    <Route path="attributes" element={<Attributes />} /> // "/demo1/attributes"
    <Route path="*" element={<InfoPage />} />            // "/demo1/*"
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but this is just hardcoding the basename. Of course I can do that, but what I'm trying to do is to is to "define the base so that it gets the folder that app files are located in".  To deploy this to 40 folders in data/www would mean changing the basename to folder name and then build it and copy things to that folder and repeat that 40 times.

Comment: @charm I see, then you may need to create a sort of external configuration/environment variable/etc to accomplish this without "hardcoding" the correct base URL within the app.

Comment: Yes. I've seen some examples that uses basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL} but I can't get that to work even in VS Code, let alone deployed.

Comment: I got this to work now with VITE env variable in development environment. Maybe I can do this somehow for prod build.

Comment: @charm That seems to align with the suggestion. 

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by changing to HashRouter. The main difference is that `/attributes` route is accessed with different url like below:

```
https://demo-machine.com/demo1/#/attributes
```

The code looks like this:

```
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
      <HashRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
          <Route path="/attributes" element={<Attributes />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<InfoPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </HashRouter>
  </StrictMode>
);
```